# Chrome extension to externally connect to any local IP

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am building an extension for chrome that should work with (externally connect to) one or more websites. To test it I have the website running on a server in the local network and connect to it from machines in the local network that have the extension installed.

I tried something like this

```
"externally_connectable": {
"matches": [
    "http://192.168.1.109:8080/*"
],
"accepts_tls_channel_id": false
},
```

in the `manifest.json` file but it didn't work. Ideally i would like to allow all urls to connect at least during development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that.

Quoting [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage):

> The URL pattern must contain at least **a second-level domain** - that is, hostname patterns like `"*"`, `"*.com"`, `"*.co.uk"`, and `"*.appspot.com"` are prohibited.

While this does not specifically disallow IPs, apparently they don't work, and under no circumstance you can give [a wildcard for any site](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/externally_connectable):

> Patterns cannot include wildcard domains nor subdomains of [(effective) top level domains](https://publicsuffix.org/list/); `*://google.com/*` and `http://*.chromium.org/*` are valid, while `<all_urls>`, `http://*/*`, `*://*.com/*`, and even `http://*.appspot.com/*` are not.

For testing, you can assign a second-level domain to your local address in the [`hosts` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) for your OS.

Comment: Thank you, what I didn't know/wanted to bother finding out, was the hosts file in windows.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by include_globes().

Like this

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "include_globs": ["http://127.0.*.1:*/*"],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
    ],
```

Comment: OMG! Nice! Thank you so much! Basically it seems like using `"include_globs"` in combination with `"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]` unlocks a much more flexible syntax. I personally have: `"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"], "include_globs": ["http://myServer:8081/*", "http://10.0.0.999:8081/*"]`